# Java Regular Expression: href without hash

Tags: java, html, regex, href

I'm trying to build a sitemap and parsing the html bodies for `href`s that doesn't have `#` (as those with hashes are just sub chapter links in some content page htmls).

My regexp now: `<a\\s[^>]*href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>`
I guess I should use `[^#]` or `!#` to exclude the `#` from `href`s but could not solve it with just trying and googling after it. Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it. Just inserted the `#` too in the `[^\"]` block. :D

```
<a\\s[^>]*href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"#]*)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

Comment: if you are on track and trying but it won't work, just try it some more. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use regex to parse HTML.

Best use an HTML parser, as eg http://jsoup.org and then

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

for (Element each: links) {
    if (each.attr("href").startsWith("#")) continue;
    ...
}
```

So much more painless than using regex, eh!